# PrimeNG p-multiselect - multiple values in a row (using ng-template)

Tags: angular, multi-select, primeng, ng-template

Is it possible to do something [like that](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CBEio.png) with PrimeNG's p-multiselect?

Comment: Have you tried to do it via *templating* ?

Comment: Yes, i tried. But the template is for each element in the list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you can do is to override PrimeNG style :

```
.ui-multiselect-item {
  float: left;
  width: 65px;
}
```

See [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/ZGQkO5xzpT31PjKz3zql?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

You can also just append styling to the tag like this:

```
p-multiselect { width: 100%;}
```

Remember to load your style file as the last css file.